# Simple AngularJS running on JSFiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

How do I make a jsfiddle out of the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="num in nums">
                {{num}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function MainCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.nums = ["1","2"];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My non working attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/zhon/3DHjg/ shows nothing and has errors.

Comment: http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/

Comment: @mark, this answers the general case. Can you write it up as an answer so I can "accept" it.

Comment: After selecting Load Type:"No wrap - in <body>" in JavaScript setting worked for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@pkozlowski.opensource has a nice [blog post](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/) about how to use jsFiddle to write AngularJS sample programs.

Answer (score 40):

You need to set some things up in jsFiddle for this to work.

First, on the left panel, under "Frameworks & Extensions", select "No wrap - in <body>".

Now, under "Fiddle Options", change "Body tag" to `<body ng-app='myApp'>`

In the JS panel, initiate your module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/1/

Comment: Why do I need to initialize my app? The example works without it.

Comment: After selecting Load Type:"No wrap - in <body>" in JavaScript setting worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

You've defined your controller in a function scope that is not accessible to angular (angular is not yet loaded). In other words you are trying to call angular library's functions and helpers like below example before getting angular library loaded.

```
function onload(){
 function MainCtrl(){}
}
```

To resolve this, switch your angular load type to be `No wrap - in <body>` like shown in screenshot.

[image]

here is a working [example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCUSh/)

Comment: I should have selected "no wrap (body)" instead of "onload"

Answer (score 2):

Click JAVASCRIPT button, choose angular version and place where u want include loaded script:
[image]

Then click HTML button and add ng-app in body tag. Its all:)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am writing my answer for those who land on this page , I was used to use **ng-module** directive but in **jsfiddle** after half an hour I realized that **ng-module** is not allowed and you see no error , and when changed that **ng-module** to **ng-app** fiddle worked very well .I just wanted to share this .And **no wrap (body)** is required too.

```
<div ng-app="appX" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <p>{{greeting}}
  </p>
</div>
```

---

```
var app=angular.module("appX",[]);
console.log(app);
app.controller("appCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.greeting="Hello World";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cloudnine/trgrjwf1/7/

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 1.4.8 has been chosen by JSFiddle as the top option for Angular V1 in its JAVASCRIPT setting panel, more restriction applies: both `ng-app` and `ng-controller` should be declared in HTML to make it work.

Sample HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="sample" placeholder="type something here...">
  <span>{{sample}}</span>
</div>
```

Sample JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y170uj84/

Also tested with the latest Angular 1.6.4, by setting as External Resource.

Answer (score 0):

For little experiments in angular 5, you can use https://stackblitz.com/. 
This site is used in angular documentation to run live demo. For example, https://stackblitz.com/angular/eybymjopmav