# AngularJS in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

There must be something else I need to do here, but I'm not sure what.

```
<div ng-app="theApp">
    <p> 1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2}} </p>
</div>

var theApp = angular.module("theApp", []);
```

With AngularJS 1.2 added is giving:

```
1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}
```

If I remove the `ng-app` attribute, then it gives the expected result.

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/yvh0e7vL/

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple AngularJS running on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733378/simple-angularjs-running-on-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angular module code needs to be accessible outside of any dom loading event that is set by default in jsfiddle

Just select `No wrap in head` from top left dropdown instead of the default `ondomReady`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yvh0e7vL/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<div ng-app="theApp">
```

to

```
 <div ng-app="">
```

Comment: But my next step is to actually have an app.