# 'Module ... is not available!' error, when trying to accomplish Angular example on jsFiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I'm trying to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for my question, but can't get my code working on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anatoly314/n0qfj4dk/) and get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module carouselApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'carouselApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Link to my example: https://jsfiddle.net/anatoly314/n0qfj4dk/

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: This answer from another SO question helped me to solve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733670/947111

Comment: See [Simple AngularJS running on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733378/simple-angularjs-running-on-jsfiddle) Think you have the same jsfiddle issue

Comment: @user2341963, thank you, it helped me to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to select values like below to deploy angularjs application on jsFiddle.

[image]

And Don't forget to remove angular.js from External Resources.

## EDIT:

If there is not the version you want to use, selecting `No wrap - in <body>` will solve the problem.

Comment: I can't choose latest versions of Angular by using `Frameworks & Extensions` (((

Comment: @Anatoly - Just try choosing No Wrap in body option under Framework and Extensions.

Comment: I agree @AjinderSingh if there is not the version you want to use.