# Google map script to angular directive

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, directive

Could someone help me translate it to angular directive?

```
var mapa;
var marker;

function mapaStart() {
mapOpc = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.348763181988076, 18.61083984375),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("doMeeting"), mapOpc);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.348763181988076, 18.61083984375),
    draggable: true,
    map: mapa,
});
marker.setMap(mapa);

// zdarzenia dla markera
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', uaktualnijWspolrzedne);
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'drag');

// zdarzenia dla mapy
google.maps.event.addListener(mapa, 'click', function (event) {
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
    uaktualnijWspolrzedne();
});

}

function uaktualnijWspolrzedne() {
var input_lat = document.getElementById('lat');
var input_lng = document.getElementById('lng');
var punkt = marker.getPosition();

input_lat.value = punkt.lat();
input_lng.value = punkt.lng();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapaStart);
```

**EDIT**

Maybe it wasnt good idea to put in on jsfiddle becouse of configuration jsfiddle .

I put it in on plnkr to make it clear:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EyPOmok6vmvA6Cc2yQws?p=preview

But when i try to implement to my project i get blank border instead google map, (module Geolocation work)

Comment: There's already a google maps directive that's part of the angular-ui project:  http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5ng84cy/5/). There was a problem in the setup and ng-app was not initialized.

```
// just a comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in configuring JSFiddle, not in your code. You need to do:

1. Remove angular.js script from resources
2. Select angular.js from dropdown in Fiddle Options (under Frameworks & Extensions)
3. Select options "No wrap - in head"

Explanations here: [Simple AngularJS running on JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733378/simple-angularjs-running-on-jsfiddle)

Comment: Please look on my Edit

Comment: For me your plunkr works just fine. Probably you already fixed it )