# Angular not working on jsfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

I can't get [this simple Angular example](https://jsfiddle.net/neptune001/afyyd6ob/) to work in Firefox. Tried Ctrl+F5 but nothing. In Chrome works fine.

I set Javascript options to: Javascript -- AngularJS 1.2.1 -- No wrap-in

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="AppName">
  <div ng-controller="OneController">
      {{title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myapp = angular.module('AppName', []);

myapp.controller('OneController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Just a text';
});
```

Comment: Which version of firefox? works fine here http://imgur.com/7bWCPbO

Comment: Try to check the console so there if there are any errors

Comment: @alex88 it says ReferenceError: angular is not defined. FF 43.0.1

Comment: Does it throws any error about fetching the angular js file? Check also the network connections. Tell me also if this works https://jsfiddle.net/afyyd6ob/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/afyyd6ob/3/ doesn't work. I tried to open fiddles created by other users and they work. Strange.

Comment: I've tried to change the load method of the javascript to be on dom load, but still nothing. Have you checked the network tab to see if the angular js is loaded?

Comment: i don't see angular in the network tab. Clicked the reload, but angular still doesn't appeared.

Comment: Don't know then, I have that right there http://imgur.com/exm3HZo

Comment: Seems to be something local. Thanks anyway.

Comment: First, on the left panel, under "Frameworks & Extensions", select "No wrap - in <body>".

Comment: Please refer the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733378/simple-angularjs-running-on-jsfiddle