# Unable to show content of array as checkboxes using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have the following in my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("TestCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.rows = [
    'Facebook',
    'Twitter',
    'Pinterest',
    'Instagram',
    'Tumblr',
    'Google'
  ];
}]);
```

and I'm trying to show the content like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
          <label ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="row.selected" ng-model="row.selected" />{{row}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

right now the items show, but I can't check the checkboxes,
check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/imzlFypG9LPTyMmt0ltP?p=preview)

Comment: works in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/imzlFypG9LPTyMmt0ltP?p=preview).. there was some angular loading issue with jsfiddle I guess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple AngularJS running on JSFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733378/simple-angularjs-running-on-jsfiddle)

Comment: @tanmay in the plunker you provided, I can't check checkboxes

Comment: You can't set a `selected` attribute on a string. Use objects for your rows, instead of strings. Those objects should have a name, and a selected attributes.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/B5HM8uDQ7O2pUNI4epSm?p=preview

Comment: @MMahrous added explanation as answer, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have your checkbox checkable, you need to pass a valid `ng-model` there. In your case, `row.selected` is invalid since every `row` is a string and not object.

You can have your `$scope.rows` array like this instead:

```
$scope.rows = [{
    name: 'Facebook',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'Twitter',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'Pinterest',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'Instagram',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'Tumblr',
    selected: false
  }];
```

Here's a [**forked plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZuCIzdvXZdSGWXlC1dSu?p=preview) which has checkboxes checkable

Comment: I can't change the array because I receive it from a Java session, but you are right about ng-model, I was able to fix it by using a different model.

Comment: @MMahrous so is your problem solved? or you want to track which of the rows get selected?

Comment: @MMahrous okay, glad I could help a little