# can't get AngularJS working in JSFiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

This extremely simple JSFiddle will not display the message.  Instead, it displays {{message}}.  Why isn't it working?
http://jsfiddle.net/vf6qushc/5/

Here is the HTML:

```
<html ng-app="root">
  <div ng-controller="index">
    <div>{{message}}</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Here is the JS/AngularJS:

```
angular.module('root', [])
    .controller("index", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello World!";
    }]);
```

Comment: JS was running too soon: http://jsfiddle.net/vf6qushc/32/ - changed it to load in the bottom of the `body`

Comment: duplication with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733378/simple-angularjs-running-on-jsfiddle

Comment: @tymeJV I see that your version works, but I don't see what changed.  Can you explain what changed in the code to make it load in the bottom of the body?  EDIT: I just found where to change that, thanks to the link provided by Houssein Zouari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was at your JavaScript loading. Remove **On Load** from here and it will work:

[image]

Change to this:
[image]

```
angular.module('root', [])
    .controller("index", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello World!";
    }]);
```

Working JSFIDDLE here : http://jsfiddle.net/mrjz386y/